# Kirchhoff's law question

Tags: homework, kirchhoffs-laws

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

[image]

I tried to solve it:

[image]

Comment: Please can you be more specific what help you need to solve the problem to get answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Draw and Redraw

First off, this site includes a schematic editor. It's helpful to others trying to help you if you will take a moment to learn to use it and apply it when asking questions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fthnjL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Second, it's a good idea to learn to redraw schematics when you are considering analysis and are just trying to understand them. Focus on reducing clutter that gets in the way of understanding what's in front of you, while also lining things up in sensible ways.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWwlX.png)</sup>

This isn't a lot different. But a few things have been removed without loss for analysis using KCL.

(You could perform two Norton-to-Thevenin conversions before analysis, as your schematic includes two Norton sources on the left and right sides. But the instructions are explicit about using KCL and I'll assume that this means you are not supposed to *also* use Norton-to-Thevenin conversions.)

### Analysis

You have three nodes: \$V_a\$, \$V_b\$, and the one I added, \$V_c\$.

Below, in developing the KCL equations I present an alternative method for you to consider. Traditional teaching tells you to make decisions about voltage differences across components. But this is fraught with greater difficulties in getting the sign right, each and every time.

The following method I use makes it much easier to produce consistently accurate results while achieving exactly equivalent equations (in slightly different initial form):

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {V_a:}\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1} + I}\\\\
  {V_b:}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2}\\\\
  {V_c:}\vphantom{\frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
      \frac{V_a}{R_1} + I\\\\
      \frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2\\\\
      \frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1} + I}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      I_1\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1} + I}\\\\
      \frac{V_c}{R_3}\\\\
      \frac{V_b}{R_3} + I
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

You also know something else. It's ***not*** KCL. But \$V_1\$ causes \$V_a=V_c+V_1\$. You could either add this as a 4th equation or you could keep the above KCL statements and just make the simple replacement, instead. I'll do the latter:

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {V_a:}\vphantom{\frac{V_c}{R_1} + I}\\\\
  {V_b:}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2}\\\\
  {V_c:}\vphantom{\frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
      \frac{V_c+V_1}{R_1} + I\\\\
      \frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2\\\\
      \frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1} + I}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_3} + \frac{V_b}{R_4} + I_2}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_c}{R_2} + \frac{V_c}{R_3}}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      I_1\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1} + I}\\\\
      \frac{V_c}{R_3}\\\\
      \frac{V_b}{R_3} + I
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

Now you have three equations and three unknowns and all of it looks as though it was developed using KCL, despite using another fact to get there.

Using the freely available [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), I find:

```
var('r1 r2 r3 r4 i1 i2 i v1 va vb vc')
eq1 = Eq( (vc+v1)/r1 + i, i1 )
eq2 = Eq( vb/r3 + vb/r4 + i2, vc/r3 )
eq3 = Eq( vc/r2 + vc/r3, vb/r3 + i )
ans = solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ vb, vc, i ] )
for i in ans:
    v = ans9[i].subs( { r1: 10, r2: 20, r3: 60, r4: 10, i1: 3, i2: 6, v1: 10 } )
    i, v, v.n()
(vb, -1160/23, -50.4347826086956)
(vc, 160/23, 6.95652173913043)
(i, 30/23, 1.30434782608696)
```

Feel free to re-arrange the earlier KCL equations I produced into whatever form you feel you need to see. There should be no problem putting it into whatever form the classwork requires through very simple algebra steps.

### Validation

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Really appreciate it .

Comment: @TharinduMadushan Thanks so much for letting me know it helped. It means a lot to me. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a voltage source connected like that by using nodal analysis you cannot find the current inside the voltage source.

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBK4iq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Lets try to apply nodal analysis for nodes A and B of the circuit.

I1-I2-Ix = 0 ->1-VA/2-Ix = 0

Ix-I3-I4 = 0 -> Ix-VB/3-VB/1 = 0

but we cant substitute anything for Ix because the current flowing inside a voltage can have any value.

Now you agree that 1)VA-VB = 1V.

What we do to get another equation is we are adding the 2 equations of the 2 nodes ->

2)1-VA/2-Ix+Ix-VB/3-VB/1 = 0+0->1-VA/2-VB/3-VB/1 =  0 ! We got rid of Ix and now we can solve the system of the equations 1) and 2).

Putting this in wolphram alpha we get VA = 1.27V , VB = 0.27V.

Now we can calculate I2 using Ohms law I2 = VA/R1 = 1.27/2 =0.635A

And now we can apply KCL to node A to find Ix  = I1-I2 = 1-0.635 = 0.365A

Comment: My example isnt the same with the exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Thevenin. Convert the 3 A current source and 10 ohm resistor to a voltage source; and the 6 A current source and the 20 ohm, 60 ohm and 10 ohm resistors to another voltage source. This gives a series circuit from which the current can be easily determined.

Current through the 10 V source comes to \$\frac {30}{23} \$ amp, clockwise.